# Create Custom API with multiple values of a parameter magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, parameter

I am trying to create a new API which calls the existing methods to get products data inside my custom method

I wanted to accept multiple values of a parameter (comma separated)
eg. parameters

```
 key           value

 id              1,2,3
```

How can I pass comma separated values as parameters

**CustomAPI/Product/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/details" method="POST">
        <service class="CustomAPI\Product\Api\DetailsInterface" method="prizeId"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**CustomAPI/Product/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="CustomAPI\Product\Api\DetailsInterface"
                type="CustomAPI\Product\Model\Details" />
</config>
```

**CustomAPI/Product/Api/DetailsInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace CustomAPI\Product\Api;

interface DetailsInterface
{
    /**
     * 
     * @api
     * @param int[] $id Prize Id.
     * @return array Products data.
     */
    public function prizeId($id);
}
```

**CustomAPI/Product/Model/Details.php**

```
<?php
namespace CustomAPI\Product\Model;
use CustomAPI\Product\Api\DetailsInterface;

class Details implements DetailsInterface
{

    /**
     * 
     * @api
     * @param int[] $id Prize Id.
     * @return array Products data.
     */
    public function prizeId($id) {
       return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your existing code for more context, normally you would only need to explode values by comma and proceed to use those values.

Comment: @VivekKumar I have added code to the question. Please take a look

Comment: Now I am getting this message{
    "message": "Invalid type for value: \"string\". Expected Type: \"string[]\".",
    "trace": null
}

Comment: as I think, you have to check your interface file CustomAPI/Product/Api/DetailsInterface.php

here it also read the comment in interface file, and currently your $id data type is string, 
so just change 
** @param int[] $id **
to 
 **@param string $id** , and it has to work